How can I make a button that changes a label's image when it has been clicked?
I was trying to change a label's image in Tkinter, but it didn't work. It didn't give me an error, but instead the image remained the same.
I made two strings that are equal to the location of the two images, and I wanted to change the photo location.

There are two possible points of failure: either you don't have the right code for changing the image, or you don't have the right code for making the button run that code. The duplicates should have you covered for either of those.

To change the image on a label in tkinter, you need to make sure of a few things:
The image you use must be in a format supported by tkinter, such as .gif, .pgm, or .ppm.
The image object needs to be stored as an instance attribute, not a local variable, to avoid being collected by the garbage collector.
Here's a simple example of how you can change the image on a label in tkinter:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
    
class App:
        def __init__(self, root):
            self.root = root
            self.root.title("Change Label Image Example")
    
            self.image1_path = "path/to/your/image1.gif"
            self.image2_path = "path/to/your/image2.gif"
    
            self.image1 = PhotoImage(file=self.image1_path)
            self.image2 = PhotoImage(file=self.image2_path)
    
            self.label = tk.Label(root, image=self.image1)
            self.label.pack()
    
            self.change_button = tk.Button(root, text="Change Image", command=self.change_image)
            self.change_button.pack()
    
        def change_image(self):
            # Check the current image and switch to the other
            current_image = self.label.cget("image")
            if current_image == str(self.image1):
                self.label.config(image=self.image2)
            else:
                self.label.config(image=self.image1)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = App(root)
        root.mainloop()

In this example:
self.image1 and self.image2 are PhotoImage objects initialized with the path to their respective images.
The label is created with image=self.image1.
A button is added to call the change_image function, which will switch the image on the label.
Make sure the image paths are correct and the images are in a format supported by tkinter. If there are still issues, ensure the images exist in the specified location and are in the correct format.

PNG is supported?
